# How to setup docker-compose to run test on github actions for intergration testing with mySQL

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, github-actions

I'm running docker-compose on my development environment, it's working fine, I can also run all tests. I've tried running it into my MacOS and Ubuntu both are working fine no errors or whatsoever. My problem is when I set up my workflows for my Github actions I'm getting this error when running my migrations:

[image]

I need this to set up my tables and run tests.

I also tried  adding this to my workflows just to test if my MYSQL is running:

```yaml
- name: testing MySQL if running
  run: mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -ppassword
```

but I get this error: `Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

I am also sure that my database and server are running via docker-compose. I'm not sure why is my application unable to connect to my MYSQL.

My assumption is, when the command `run` is being invoked in GitHub actions it runs on a separate ubuntu process because on my `yml` file I have `runs-on: ubuntu-20.04` that's why it's not seeing MYSQL connection. So since I have 5 `run` commands on my `yml` file to run my job it spins up 5 different ubuntu. Is there a way to run a single instance and run all commands in a single instance? This my first doing DevOps by the way so I'm clueless.

Here is a link to my yml file: [Link](https://github.com/artoodeeto/ggpo-server/actions/runs/1168508284/workflow)

Here is the link to my latest error running the workflows: [Link](https://github.com/artoodeeto/ggpo-server/runs/3427606947?check_suite_focus=true)

**UPDATE:**

Actually, I don't have to run any migrations since this is only for testing on pull requests I just have to create the `test_db`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to run tests on any pull requests without using docker. I just have to run MySQL using this github action [shogo82148/actions-setup-mysql@v1.3.0](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/actions-setup-mysql)

this is the updated workflow:

```yaml
      - uses: shogo82148/actions-setup-mysql@v1.3.0
        with:
          mysql-version: '8.0'
          auto-start: true
      - name: create test database
        run: mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -e 'CREATE DATABASE test_db;'
      - name: show databases
        run: mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -e 'SHOW DATABASES;'
      - name: setup user
        run: mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';"
      - name: flush privileges
        run: mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -e 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES' -ppassword
```